# How to remove the default interstitial ad from app

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

```
       public void adShow() {
       mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
       mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-581420244534656/2222222");

    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        mInterstitialAd.show();
    } else {
        requestNewInterstitial();
        reseter();
    }

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            requestNewInterstitial();
            reseter();
        }
    });
}

private void requestNewInterstitial() {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("3D9834hiqewuiry48937498urequE")
            .build();
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

}

I have tested the use of interstitial in my app using the default ad from google and it's working but now what must i do to make sure that the default orange ad is not displayed to users when I publish my app? I already have the AdUnitId.

Answer (score 0):

So long as you have set a valid Ad unit id from the ad provider you're using, you should get real ads. The reason you most likely aren't seeing real ads is because of the line `.addTestDevice("3D9834hiqewuiry48937498urequE")` which basically says "Only show me the default orange ad on **this** device".

So, if you always test your app on the same device, this line is disabling real ads from appearing while you test (which is what you want). But this line will only disable real ads on a single device, the one you're using. On other devices, users will see real ads.

Comment: I actually solved it with this peace of codes.     private void requestNewInterstitial() {
        AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest.build());
    }    I hope it's not wrong to do that. M new to both java and android studio